# Sharepoint Designer - how to restart a workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer, restart

Is there a way, through SPD (w/o the state machine extension), to restart a workflow?

Answer (score 0):

There are 'Stop Workflow' and 'Start Workflow' actions you could combine.

Comment: The self-reference doesn't work, and doing it through an intermediary workflow doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found an alternative, but the route to go using the STOP and Start actions is that you have to pause for at least a minute using another workflow before the restart the intended workflow, because you can't run the same workflow on top of another instance of the same workflow